# Maven web app with EJB3

Tags: web-applications, maven-2, ejb-3.0, jboss7.x

I'm a newbie in EJB3 and maybe such issue was discussed earlier but I didn't found any solid explanation. I have to implement simple Maven2 web application with EJB3 technology (including JPA2 entities). Could someone explain what archetype or project structure and what depencies I need to use step by step? By the way, this app should be deployed to application server (ideally directly from IDEA). AS is JBoss 7. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [JDF](http://www.jboss.org/jdf/). It has a lot of information on getting started. Also have a look at [JDF Stacks](http://www.jboss.org/jdf/stack/stacks/) for maven dependencies. There are BOM's there for Java EE dependencies.